# Start then Stop Windows Service very fast, the OnStop method did not call

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, windows-services

I am doing a windows service (call it SampleService), every is fine. When I started then stopped service through Windows Service Management Tool (service.msc), it run properly.

But my service will be request Start and Stop by another application. So I will not use Windows Service Management Tool in this case.

This is my service implement.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

public partial class SampleService : ServiceBase
{
    public SampleService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.WriteLog("OnStart");
        // Doing start service logic down here
        // Some service logic like create some files.
        // Or just leave it empty like a brand new Windows Service.
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.WriteLog("OnStop");
        // Doing clean service logic down here.
        // Some service logic like: delete files.  
        // Or just leave it empty like a brand new Windows Service.
    }

    static readonly object synObject = new object();

    public void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Write log.
        lock (synObject)
        {
            using (var wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\logfile.txt", true))
            {   
                wr.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "-" + message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is code logic use to Start and Stop service inside my another application. I can not modify this another application. The bellow source code simulate what happen.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("SampleService");

         // start service
         sc.Start();

         // doing some logic cost deltaTime or just stand by in deltaTime.
         Thread.Sleep(deltaTime);
         try
         {
             // stop service first time, nothing happen.
             sc.Stop();
         }
         catch
         {
         }

         try
         {
             // stop service second times, by dump people or apllication.
             sc.Stop();
         }
         catch
         {
             // It got an exception here: "The service cannot accept control messages at this time".
             // But the service did stopped.
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is:"When deltaTime is too short (bellow 3000ms with empty OnStart(), OnStop()), Service will stop incorrectly. The output log OnStop will never show up, that mean OnStop method did not called.

My service will doing clean up work in OnStop (like delete some file), but if it not be called, these files still there.

I cannot change logic of another application but I can change SampleService.

I want to ask:

1. Is this an Windows Service base issue and I cant do anything with it?
2. What ever it is, can I do clean up some where else?

Thank you!

Comment: Unlikely to be a Windows problem.  *Might* be a .NET problem, though that's not all that much more likely.  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Never use Thread.Sleep(), it is the most inaccurate possible way to ensure that something happened.  Use ServiceController.WaitForStatus() instead.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(deltaTime) just a simulation of user action. They click Start, wait a little bit, then click Stop.
sc.Start() is stand for request [Start SampleService] from another application.
sc.Stop() is stand for request [Stop SampleService] from another application.
Thread.Sleep(deltaTime) simulate the duration between Start and Stop request from another application.

In another application, it could Start then Stop SampleService immediately.
I cannot do anything to change another application, all I can do is change SampleService.

Comment: Surely you are missing the point, you can't click Stop in service manager until the service actually started.  Your code does not check that the service actually started.  Calling Stop() when the service isn't running yet doesn't do anything.  As you found out.  Using WaitForStatus() is not optional.

Comment: As I told before, I am not Stop service from service manager, I Start and Stop it from another application. 
It run properly when using service manager.

Comment: _"The output log OnStop will never show up, that mean OnStop method did not called"_ - that's not certain. I would suspect your logging code. The Services MMC is just a GUI for the Service Control Manager, clicking "Stop" from there does exactly the same as your code.

Comment: The code provided doesn't build for me.  Looks like both `InitializeComponent` and `WriteLog` are missing?

Comment: You can create a Windows Service following this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx
And the WriteLog method just simple create an txt file and add text into it.

Comment: @KenWhite I dont understand what you mean. I am the poster. I just try to explant to HarryJohnston how to make my code run.
CodeCaster
I have updated logging method.
About services.msc it always have a delta time enough for service change to Started status, then we could stop it properly.
But in another application, they did not design that services could stop when it is Started status. They just force it to stop by sc.Stop method and didnt care about service status. Saddly, I cant change another application.

Comment: I suspect that the garbage collection isn't happening quickly enough to allow the stream to be flushed before the process is terminated.  Try adding `wr.Close()` immediately after `wr.WriteLine()`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Beside WriteLog method, my service also have delete file logic in OnStop method, not only WriteLog isnt work, delete logic cant be reached too, and my file still be there.
All I want is if I can do delete file logic somewhere else, not in OnStop method in case service is stop abnormal like that.

Comment: Your code as currently posted works perfectly well for me.  Have you actually tried to reproduce your problem using *only* the template code provided by Visual Studio plus the two bits of code as currently posted?

Comment: Yes, I have reproduced my problem with default template code of Visual Studio and just add WriteLog method, I also add wr.Close as your advise but OnStop method still not been call in my case.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  What version of Windows?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Windows 7 Enterprise, 64bit